# Перевод интерполяции в ангуляре

Tags: angular, i18n, интерполяция

Имеется следующий код:

```
...
<!--If is a single link-->
    <a [routerLink]="[menuitem.path]" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'link'" class="nav-link">
        <i class="material-icons">{{menuitem.icontype}}</i>
        <p i18n="Sidebar@@menuSingleItem">{{menuitem.title}}</p>
    </a>
<!--If it have a submenu-->
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{menuitem.collapse}}" *ngIf="menuitem.type === 'sub'" (click)="updatePS()" class="nav-link">
        <i class="material-icons">{{menuitem.icontype}}</i>
        <p i18n="Sidebar@@menuItemWithChildren">{{menuitem.title}}
            <b class="caret"></b></p>
    </a>
...
```

Это часть Ангулярного проекта. Я пытаюсь сделать проект мультиязыковым. Для этого использую встроенную **i18n** (https://angular.io/guide/i18n). Проблема в том, что запись HTML в виде **{{text}}** воспринимается как некая интерполяция (что это такое я сам не знаю), и чтобы я не делал в .xlf-файле, перевод не получается. Я перерыл уже весь интернет (как мне кажется) и нигде ничего. Не может же быть, что я единственный у кого возникла такая проблема. Кто сталкивался с этим или знает где посмотреть, пожалуйста поделитесь буду очень благодарен.

Кстати ангуляр выдаёт такое:

```
...
<trans-unit id="menuSingleItem" datatype="html">
    <source><x id="INTERPOLATION" equiv-text="{{menuitem.title}}"/></source>

    <context-group purpose="location">
      <context context-type="sourcefile">app/sidebar/sidebar.component.ts</context>
      <context context-type="linenumber">99</context>
    </context-group>
    <note priority="1" from="description">Sidebar</note>
</trans-unit>
...
```

Вторая строка просто убивает: **x id="INTERPOLATION"**

Comment: В чем ваш вопрос? `Вторая строка просто убивает` - это можно отнести к вопросу или это эмоции? :-) не забегайте вперед паровоза с интернационализацией, если еще не знаете что такое интерполяция

Comment: Это эмоции, но и часть вопроса. Самый главный вопрос: как работать с **x id="INTERPOLATION"**?
Например если надо создать перевод с множественным числом или выборов вариантов, то i18n генерирует строку **x id="ICU"**. В документации подробно расписано и показано что и как делать дальше. А если генерируется интерполяция? Как работать с этим?

Comment: интерполяция не генерируется :-)

Comment: Может всё-таки можно несколько по подробней об этом, рас уж вы разбираетесь. От того, что я только-что узнал, что нечто под названием интеполяция вероятнее всего не генерируется вовсе, легче мне не стало.

Comment: нет, тут не дело в том, что легче или не легче, я наоборот хочу направить ваши силы в правильное русло, вы сами понимаете, что не умея в руке держать топор - дерева не срубишь. Так и данной ситуации - больше углубитесь в азы angular + интерполяция описана на первых страницах их документации, а потом уже поэтапно дойдете до интернационализации. В текущий момент времени вы потратите больше сил и нервов на нахождение ошибки в вашем коде без знания азов, а если копнете базисы - i18n будет легче вам в понимании. Cheers :-)